# Reusing Ethereum deployed smart contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

I have developed and deployed my token and stacking contracts on the ethereum main net, now I want to deploy them on the Binance Smart Chain(BSC), my question is Do I need to modify my current written smart contracts or I can just use the same smart contracts and just deploy them on the BSC.

Comment: not need to modify anything (except addresses of other contracts if you use some). that is the idea of a copy cat

Comment: Thanks, so I just have to redeploy them understood.